# Visual Studio Template: Custom Template category

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-templates

How to put Custom Visual Studio template, written in C#, under other custom category (not under "Visual C#")?

Visual Studio allows to create custom template category, but it will be created under the language category template written in:

[image: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/Tools-IDE/847664/AddNewItemTemplateInCategory.png]

Answer (score 0):

In .vstemplate file where has a  element. It used to category the item template so that it appears under the specified group in the Add New Item dialog box.

According to the explanation for [Text Value of ProjectType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5we0w25d.aspx#Anchor_2), it only supports CSharp, VisualBasic and Web.

> This value specifies the type of project the template will create, and
>   **must contain one of the following values**:
>
> **CSharp**: Specifies that the template creates a Visual C# project or
>   item.
>
> **VisualBasic**: Specifies that the template creates a Visual Basic
>   project or item.
>
> **Web**: Specifies that the template creates a Web project or item. If the
>   ProjectType element contains this value, the language of the project
>   or item is defined in the ProjectSubType Element (Visual Studio
>   Templates).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sadly. I thought it is possible to create own base category, since Wix Toolset and .Net Core introduced its own.

Comment: In Add New Item dialog box, all items will list under C# Items tab. But in New Project dialog box, you could set you own custom category that doesn't under C# items. The categories in the New Project reflect the directory structures that exist in the installed and custom template locations. You can modify these directory structures to organize your templates in a way that makes sense to you. You could change the <OutputSubPath> tag value as the category path in vstemplate file. Please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3kkate1.aspx#Anchor_1